# Every radical ideal in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is contained in at least $2$ maximal ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Assume that $I$ is a proper radical ideal of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ which is not a maximal ideal where $k$ is a field. Prove that $I$ is contained in at least two maximal ideals.

Now it is easy to prove the claim using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. I wonder if there is a more elementary argument to prove this claim.

Comment: I am convinced that this claim is actually equivalent to the Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it is sufficiently elementary, but you can proof this using Noether normalization and Going Up.

Let $I$ be radical ideal, such that $R=k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]/I$ is a local ring. We have to show that $R$ is a field.

By Noether normalization, we have a finite map

$$k[y_1, \dotsc, y_d] \hookrightarrow R$$

Since this map is integral, we know that an ideal in $R$ is maximal if and only if its contraction is. In particular - using that $R$ is local - there is only one maximal ideal of $k[y_1, \dotsc, y_d]$, which is a contraction of a prime of $R$.

Let $\mathfrak p \subset R$ be a minimal prime ideal and $\mathfrak q$ be the contraction along this map. By Going Up, all maximal ideals of $k[y_1, \dotsc, y_d]$ containing $\mathfrak q$ are obtained as a contraction from a prime of $R$. By the argument above, there is only one such maximal ideal. Thus we have shown, that $\mathfrak q \subset k[y_1, \dotsc, y_d]$ is a radical ideal, which is contained in a unique maximal ideal. Using induction (note that $d < n$), we get that $\mathfrak q$ is maximal, i.e. $\mathfrak p$ was maximal.

This shows that $R$ is a zero-dimensional local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak p = \operatorname{nil} R$. It is also reduced, hence $\mathfrak p=0$ and thus $R$ is a field.

---

Of course you can use similiar arguments to obtain the Nullstellensatz from Noether normalization and Going Up.

I am pretty sure that basically every proof of this statement will come very close to proving the Nullstellensatz as well.

Comment: Yeah, I am also aware that Noether Normalization Theorem can be used to prove the claim. I am suspicious that it is more elementary than using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. In fact, I want to use the claim to prove that there exists no finitely generated local $k$-algebra except field extensions of $k$, but you directly prove this claim.

Comment: You mean that there exists no finitely generated local **reduced** $k$-algebra except (finite) field extensions of $k$. Do you know the formulation of the Nullstellensatz in terms of Jacobson rings? This is also a trivial consequence of this, but I did not want to use it, because that would have been using Nullstellensatz.

Comment: If you skip the reducedness, you have things like $k[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, forgot the assumption that it is reduced. Yes, I know the Jacobson rings formulation. Just like you said, now I believe that it is equivalent to the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: There haven't been any other answers, so I'll accept yours.